# Can't bind from API data Angular 6

Tags: javascript, arrays, angular, typescript, get

I'm working with API to get data and bind it to the HTML, i get to show the response on the console but once i try to bind data to the User screen i cannot, nothing is showing

My HTML:

```
<ul *ngFor="let item of items; let i of index">
 <li class="fa fa-plus">{{item.name}} - {{i}}</li>
</ul>
```

My TS:

```
id: number;
name:string;
imageUrl: string;
items:any = {}; 
ngOnInit() {
this.getItems();
}
getItems() {
this.getItemsService.getItems().subscribe(
  res => {
    console.log(res)
    if (res.Success) {
      this.items = res;
    }
  }
)
```

}

I'm trying to get data from an array of objects this is why i defined items as an object, if i tried to define it as an array, same result, cannot bind data to HTML

My API Link:

http://5a12745f748faa001280a746.mockapi.io/v1/stores/item

Any questions or missing info tell me but kindly i need help binding this data

Comment: items:any = []; change to this

Comment: This won't correct his issue.

Comment: and let i = index is also fine for index

Comment: try using `{{items | json}}` Just to check values are coming in template or not, Also please post what does your `console.log` returns

Comment: i tried change it to array and didnt work

Comment: yes the console is showing the data

Comment: Have you tried with *ngIf="items" and then iterate?

Comment: no i didn't, will do now

Comment: no nothing happens, response is in the console, and no errors in the code

Comment: Please produce a plucker

Comment: issue resolved, thanks for your help ^_^

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two things, HTML first : `let i = index` is the syntax.

The second one, you have a condition in your binding :

```
if (res.Success) {
  this.items = res;
}
```

This implies that your response has a `Success` property.

I checked your API link, and it doesn't.

So in your service, either you use `Http from @angular/http` or `HttpClient from @angular/common/http`. Here are the two syntaxes :

```
// Http
return this.http.get('url').map(res => res.json());
// HttpClient
return this.http.get<any[]>('url');
```

For the condition, change to the following, to check if you have data. You don't need to check for success because you have a special callback for that. This means you will always have succeed where the condition is.

```
if (res) {
  this.items = res;
}
```

Comment: HttpClient fron Angular forms? , i imported it from angular common